# Checking the html syntax

Tags: html, conditional-statements

I would like to get check on this html line.

```
 <div class="activity-title {{or (unless currentActivity.banner) (if isUsingIframe) 'no-banner-image'}}">
```

Comment: We don't do code reviews here, nor are we a substitute for an HTML validator. Now if you'd like to revise to ask whether special characters such as braces can occur in HTML attribute values, feel free to do that instead.

Comment: Yes, if you face any error, you can reproduce it or else, atleast you can show the use case of your code, so that it is easy to find correct or not

Comment: I wonder about this part in html syntax `{{or (if ...) (unless ...) }}`

Comment: HTML has no `or`, `if`, or `unless` but javascript does. Looks like you are thinking of any one of a myriad of JS libraries or frameworks out there that use this kind of syntax in the markup, no?